# How to initialize viewModel using MEF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, mef

I have a Module called ModuleMenu. In this module I have a UserControl called MenuView and a Corresponding ViewModel called UserControlViewModel. I also have a class called Module. All the code is as given below:

MenuView.xmal

```
<UserControl ..............>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, Converter={StaticResource dummy}}" DisplayMemberPath="MenuItemName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}" >

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>

    </ListBox>

</UserControl>
```

MenuView.xaml.cs

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class MenuView : UserControl
{
    public MenuView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

UserControlViewModel.cs

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class MenuViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    IServiceFactory _ServiceFactory;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MenuViewModel(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        _ServiceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    protected override void OnViewLoaded()
    {
        _MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();

        WithClient<IMenuItemService>(_ServiceFactory.CreateClient<IMenuItemService>(), menuItemClient =>
            {
                MenuItem[] menuItems = menuItemClient.GetAllParentMenuItemsWithChildren();
                if (menuItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
                    {
                        _MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
                    }

                    _SelectedMenuItem = _MenuItems[2];
                }

            });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _MenuItems;

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _MenuItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MenuItems != value)
            {
                _MenuItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => MenuItems, false);
            }
        }
    }

    private MenuItem _SelectedMenuItem;

    public MenuItem SelectedMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedMenuItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedMenuItem != value)
            {
                _SelectedMenuItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedMenuItem);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Module.cs

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(Module), InitializationMode=InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]
public class Module : IModule
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Module(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MenubarRegion].Add(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MenuView>());
    }
}
```

Now in my main Project I have a class called BootStrapper.cs as follows:

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ModuleMenu.Module).Assembly));
    }
}
```

In my App.xaml:

```
<Application ..............>
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type modMenu:MenuViewModel}">
            <modMenu:MenuView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And finally in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();

    }
}
```

When I run the application I get shell as expected. It shows me MenuView, but the data in MenuView is not loaded. I tried to debug it using a dummy converter and show that the viewModel is never initialized.

So, now my question is how can I initialize the viewModel?

**update:**

After trying your code I get exception as follows:

An exception has occurred while trying to add a view to region 'MenubarRegion'.

```
- The most likely causing exception was was: 
    'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation  
    error occured while trying to get instance of type MenuView, key "" ---> 
    Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation 
    error occured while trying to get instance of type MenuView, key ""

at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.MefServiceLocatorAdapter
                  .DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)

at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase
                  .GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase
                  .GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)

at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase
                  .GetInstance(Type serviceType)

at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionViewRegistry
                  .CreateInstance(Type type)

at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionViewRegistry
                  .<>c__DisplayClass1.<RegisterViewWithRegion>b__0()

at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.Behaviors
                  .AutoPopulateRegionBehavior
                  .OnViewRegistered(Object sender, ViewRegisteredEventArgs e)'.

 But also check the InnerExceptions for more detail or call 
                  .GetRootException().
```

When I take a look at inner exception, I get the following error message:

```
{"Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type MenuView, key \"\""}
```

**update2:**

Here is the Export of type ServiceFactory :

```
[Export(typeof(IServiceFactory))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    public T CreateClient<T>() where T : IServiceContract
    {
        return ObjectBase.Container.GetExportedValue<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You define a `DataTemplate` as a view for your viewmodel, but don't actually use it.

There are many ways to solve your issue using Prism, please refer to [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec17).

You could set the `DataContext` property of your view in XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <my:MyViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

You could create a viewmodel in the view's constructor:

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

A better way would be to import the viewmodel via dependency injection:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public MyView(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

You could use the Prism's viewmodel location services:

```
<MyView prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"/>
```

Last but not least: you could use a `DataTemplate` too, but you should set a `DataContext` of your objects to let WPF create the view for you, and don't create the view in code.

---

**UPDATE:**
So, you want to use the `DataTemplate` feature. Well, that is not a 'Prism' way to do things, because in that case the view will be created by WPF, not by the Prism's `IRegion`. But that's possible anyway.

I'll explain the difference: in all the other (Prism) methods, a view is the 'master', it will be created first, then an appropriate viewmodel will be created and attached to the view. In Prism, you define what views should be created, when (navigation) and where (regions). In the `DataTemplate` method, the viewmodel (data) is the 'master', it will be created first, and WPF determines how to display them creating a view. So in this case, you can't use Prism's regions and navigation, because WPF handles all the things.

So I really suggest you to use any of the above methods for this, but not the `DataTemplate` one.

You create your view as follows:

```
_regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MenubarRegion].Add(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MenuView>());
```

I would suggest you to change that to:

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MenubarRegion, typeof(MenuView));
```

Using `ServiceLocator` directly is not a good pattern (unless you can't avoid it), so let Prism instantiate the view for you.

In your view's constructor, just add a dependency injection of the viewmodel, and set the view's `DataContext` to it. Voilà! You've got it.

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class MenuView : UserControl
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MenuView(MenuViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Using `DataTemplate`, you can do it only in an 'old plain WPF way'. You have to create an instance of the viewmodel manually and expose it as a property of the parent (shell's) viewmodel (or make it static, which is a poor approach however).

```
<Window>
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding MenuViewModelInstace}"/>
</Window>
```

WPF will then create the view for you to display the viewmodel, but you should define this directly in XAML markup, as I mentioned before. Prism can't help you here.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Can you expand the explanation of your last point (using DataTemplate)????

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply as I was not notified about the update in your answer. Now, I have tried to implement your code and now I get an error as mentioned in Update part of my question.

Comment: @Vishal, it's not a good practice to post some repro links to external storages. Regarding the error: please ensure that all your dependency injections can be resolved. The exception states that the view cannot be instantiated. This is because Prism cannot resolve your viewmodel dependency injection, which might be caused by the fact that the viewmodel itself cannot be instantiated. Are you sure there are some exports that satisfy the `IServiceFactory` import?

Comment: I apologise, but I am very new to Dependency Injection, MEF and Prism. So, I asked you about the problem. And I think I have an export that satisfies the IServiceFactory import. Please check Update2 in question for more details.

Comment: @Vishal, well, you have to find out why the MEF container can't compose the `MenuView` part. There is something that prevents the container to instantiate the object or any of its dependency. Check that all of them are marked with the `ExportAttribute`, have matching export/import contracts and correct constructors (e.g. marked with `ImportingConstructorAttribute`). Also, check that there are no ambiguous exports with same contract if you import only single objects. You could set a breakpoint in your bootstrapper and inspect the container to find out what's actually there.

Comment: I have tried to check everything and I think I am doing everything right. Can you please check the sample project just once whenever you get time? It took many days for me, but for an experienced developer like you it might be a matter of 2 minutes to solve this problem.

Comment: @Vishal, I have tried to access your sample project, but it is not public.

Comment: Sorry, I think the project is deleted from the drive by mistake. I will upload a new one in just a bit and will give you link. Thanks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0ba0wtWUstaEVJY3M/view?usp=sharing Please check the link above

Comment: @Vishal, I've taken a look on your "sample" project. This doesn't really seem to be a sample, but rather your complete solution. Furthermore, it does not even compile because there are missing projects referenced. Please be aware that nobody will study your whole (not compilable) code just for fun. I would suggest you to create a small project that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Sorry to say but I have left the idea of using MEF.

Comment: @dymanoid I am also facing the same problem. Can you please help me? Here is a link to my sample project. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2XAE1EBI6rU3VsYjVyQmhFRFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Khushi & for the record, i had the exact same issue and would like to share my solution here. In my case i had to copy the Module.dll.config file in the bin folder (shell's one) to avoid this issue. Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation isn't known by the module without it and the region activation fail with the {"Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type MenuView, key \"\""} error.