# How to set data context for user control with prism wpf?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, datacontext

This my **view.xaml**:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="grdFormSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <local:StudentUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Above I added a `StudentUserControl` in view.xaml.

**StudentUserControl.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class StudentUserControl : UserControl
{
   public StudentUserControl(StudentViewModel ViewModel)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = ViewModel;
   }
}
```

**StudentViewModel.cs:**

```
public StudentViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IUnityContainer container)
{
     _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
     _container = container;
}
```

It is throwing an error in xaml, as it's expecting a parameterless constructor!

How to set the `DataContext` for the `UserControl`?
What is the best approach to do it?

Comment: So are you trying to have your UserControl use a different ViewModel than the view it is hosted on?

Comment: Where does the `StudentViewModel` instance come from?

Comment: There is no need to explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl. It is usually inherited from one of the parent controls in the XAML tree.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28537402/2846483) to a similar question.

Comment: As my StudentViewModel constructor has IEventAggregator, IUnityContainer, IRegionManager parameters, how this params will be resolved?

Comment: I am initializing <local:StudentUserControl> in the xaml, is there other way of doing this from main view model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parameter from the constructor of the view:

```
public partial class StudentUserControl : UserControl
{
    public StudentUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

It shouldn't be there if you want to be able to create an instance of the view in your XAML markup like you are doing here:

```
<local:StudentUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Besides, you shouldn't explicitly set the `DataContext` of the view in the code-behind anyway. The `DataContext` should in most cases be inherited from the parent element, i.e. view.xaml in your case, and if you explicitly set the DataContext in the constructor of the view, you break the inheritance.

If the parent view has no `DataContext` for some reason, you could use Prism's view model locator to create a view model:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.StudentUserControl"
    ...
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
```

Please refer to the following link for more information about this: http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/

Comment: As my StudentViewModel constructor has IEventAggregator, IUnityContainer, IRegionManager parameters, how this params will be resolved?

Comment: The view model locator should take care of this for you provided that you have set up Prism correctly.

Comment: separated views and viewModels into different libraries, in this case viewModelLocator is not working?

Comment: Didn't you read the blog post? You need to change the default conventions by calling the ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver method.

Comment: I read the blog, am facing issues to implement. Can you share an example with views and view models in different projects

Comment: There is an example of how to call the ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelType method available in the blog post. Please ask a new question where you provide a full repo of your issue if you need any further help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You could also set your DataContext in the view.xaml

add your viewModel namespace

```
xmlns:viewModel="using:YourApp.ViewModels"
```

then in your xaml markup set it this way

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:StudentViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

you get a ViewModel property in your view, of Type StudentViewModel